# ServiceStack & Swagger - ApiMember as Path and Query

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I'm searching for a solution for the following Problem, concerning the Swagger Integration in ServiceStack.

I have my RequestObject with a required Property Id. 
I want to provide the following routes:

```
[Route("/User/byId/{Id}", "GET", Summary = @"test", Notes = "test")]
[Route("/User/byId", "GET", Summary = @"test", Notes = "test")]
```

Basically this should leave the choice of providing the Id in a Query String or as Path to the ServiceConsumer.

The Swagger UI correctly displays the 2 Routes, but is not testable for both ways, because the API-Member Attribute does not allow to specify it as ParameterType 'path' or 'query'.

Source: https://gist.github.com/JohannesFerner/5317496

Is there any way, to provide an API-Member Specification, specifically to the according Route, or to define that it is valdid as Path and Query?

Like this:

```
[ApiMember(Name = "Id", ParameterType="path,query", Description = "User Id",  DataType = "int", IsRequired = true)]
```

Comment: My understanding of this - https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Parameters - is that a parameter can only be one of either 'body', 'path' or 'query'. And a parameter name must be unique. Based on this, it doesn't seem possible to have a parameter represented as both 'path' and 'query'.

Comment: Thanks, that was also my understanding. 
Seems as if there is no way, to define the parameterType for both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this I find it easiest to create two separate DTO classes to facilitate documenting each route correctly in Swagger. The DTO classes might have identical properties (`Id` in this case, it looks like), and different `Route` and `ApiMember` attributes. You would have two service methods, one for each DTO, and they could call a shared method, passing in the value of the `Id` property, so that the bulk of the implementation isn't duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide ApiMember multiple times. So expanding on your example:

```
[Route("/User/byId/{Id}", "GET", Summary = @"test", Notes = "test")]
[Route("/User/byId", "GET", Summary = @"test", Notes = "test")]
public class TestRoute
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Id", ParameterType="path", Description = "User Id",  DataType = "int", IsRequired = false)]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Id", ParameterType="query", Description = "User Id",  DataType = "int", IsRequired = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This of course results in a spec for two routes, both accepting an id query param or path param.

If you use swagger-codegen this will unfortunately create a call that looks like this:

```
public GetTestId(int Id1, int Id2 = null)
```